# Console error when Google map is not displayed/used

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a Google map on my contact page and it works fine, no console errors. However on other pages I get the following error message, presumably because it can't find the map:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null
    at Object._.$f (js?key=MY-KEY:81)
    at new tg (js?key=MY-KEY:87)
    at init (main.js:292)
```

I've seen a few posts but most of them seem to document getting the map to work/display but in this instance there isn't meant to be a map on the page.

I guess this could be resolved by just calling the javascript on the contact page but the script is in my global .js file and it's loaded on every page.

Is there a way to resolve this error, keeping the script in a global, external file?

Here's my Google map script for reference:

```
/* 
 * When the window has finished loading create our google map below.
 */

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

/* 
 * Basic options for a simple Google Map. For more options see:
 * https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions
 *
 * 1. How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
 * 2. The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required).
 * 3. How you would like to style the map. This is where you would paste any
 *    style found on Snazzy Maps.
 * 4. Prevent map from being draggable.
 * 5. Hide map/satellite toggle.
 * 6. Hide "Street View" button.
 */

function init() {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15, /* [1] */ 
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(LAT-VALUE, LNG-VALUE), /* [2] */ 
        draggable: false, /* [4] */
        mapTypeControl: false, /* [5] */
        streetViewControl: false, /* [6] */
        styles: /* [3] */
            [{"stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"gamma":1}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"weight":"2.00"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#9c9c9c"}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":45}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#eeeeee"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#7b7b7b"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"fill","stylers":[{"weight":"1.00"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"hue":"#a3cd39"},{"gamma":1},{"saturation":"50"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#46bcec"},{"visibility":"on"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#c8d7d4"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#070707"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"}]}]
    };

    /* 
     * Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map. We are using a div with
     * id="map" seen below in the <body>
     */

     var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

    /* 
     * Create the Google Map using our element and options defined above.
     *
     * 1. Map varible.
     * 2. Marker variable so we can specify a retina image and resize.
     */

    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions); /* [1] */
    var mapIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("img/interface/map-marker@2x.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(100,78)); /* [2] */

    /* 
     * Let's also add a marker while we're at it.
     */

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(LAT-VALUE, LNG-VALUE),
        map: map,
        flat: true,
        title: 'TITLE-HERE',
        icon: mapIcon
    });
}
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: How is it possible that the line `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);` does not fail? Google object (or `google.maps`) should not be defined I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would a simple if/else query to detect if the 'map' id tag exists on the page resolve the error?

For example:

```
var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
if (mapElement !== null) {
    // draw the map
}
```

Or:

```
if (document.getElementById('map')) {
    // draw the map
}
```

Comment: Is there a preference out of those two methods? I guess I'd just need to wrap `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);` in it?

Comment: Both are much the same; the top method is more readable in my opinion. The bottom will also return `null` if the map id doesn't exist (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) for more info on falsy values).

Answer (score 0):

var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

```
if(mapElement != undefined || mapElement != '')
{
     var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions); /* [1] */
     var mapIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("img/interface/map-           marker@2x.png", null, null, null, new google.maps.Size(100,78));

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(LAT-VALUE, LNG-VALUE),
    map: map,
    flat: true,
    title: 'TITLE-HERE',
    icon: mapIcon
  });
}
```

Comment: Add a description to your answer, please.